# my svn diff is not working?

Tags: svn, unix

I am running "post-review" which effectively calls svn diff in my work area. However upon running the command i get the following error message:

```
Failed to execute command: ['svn', 'diff', '--diff-cmd=diff']
 "svn: Directory 'src/third-party/src/boost_1_49_0/tools/build/v2/engine/bootstrap/.svn' containing working copy admin area is missing\n"]
```

Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check-out your folder to a different location and then copy its .svn folder back into the original folder.

MayBe :)

Edit : Have you accidentally deleted .svn folder ?

Comment: i will try that, i am also seeing the following - svn: Directory 'src/third-party/src/boost_1_49_0/tools/build/v2/engine/bootstrap/.svn' containing working copy admin area is missing

Comment: Check that : http://www.devcha.com/2008/03/svn-directory-svn-containing-working.html . if it's not that I do not know